# CISCO router GUI management

Tags: cisco, database, graphical-user-interface

Is there any simple solution to connect to routers database with GUI?
I mean is it even possible to find an application which could do the configuration without the need to push commands?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes

SDM for ISRs, and ASDM for ASAs, CCP for the newest devices.

Comment: How can I know which software I need if I can not see the router itself and I do not know it's model?

Comment: `sh ver` on the CLI will tell you what model it is.

Comment: Ok, so it is ISR. CISCO 861.  I've downloaded and installed SDM. It looks like simple aaplication, when I enter routers LAN ip, the connection fails. Do you have any ideas why?

Comment: Directions for enabling SDM on an ISR: http://www.cisco.com/en/US/prod/collateral/routers/ps5318/prod_qas0900aecd80483a4f.pdf